# Write a format variable to an unformatted list, and create a new formatted variable

Tags: python-3.x, format

I have an unformatted list of lists, each containing six string elements.

I would like to iterate through the lists and for each string define a variable to change the string to a `datetime` or `float` variable.

For example:

```
list_a = [['str1', 'str2', 'str3', 'str4', 'str5', 'str6'], ['str7', 'str8', 'str9', 'str10', 'str11', 'str12']]

for i in list_a:
    date = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(i[0]) / 1000)
    j = float(i[1])
    k = float(i[2])
    l = float(i[3])
    m = float(i[4])
    n = float(i[5])
    format_i = "{}, {}, {}, ..."\n".format(date, j, k, l, m, n)
```

If I were creating a .text / .json / .csv file, I would then have the option to `.write()` the created format variable to the file being created, but I'm wondering how to apply the format variable to `i for i in list_a` and set the resulting, formatted lists in `list_a` to a new list variable, say `list_b`?

Most questions on stackoverflow to do with the `format()` function focus around appending text to a string, so not had much luck with a solution.

Any help appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Are the elements in `list_a` strings or other lists?

Comment: There are multiple lists containing 6 strings each in 'list_a'

Comment: Is `list_a` a list of lists, or a list of strings? Your example shows `list_a` as a list of strings and the subsequent code doesn't make much sense as it's written

Comment: I have edited the query to show multiple lists within 'list_a'

Comment: How many elements does each of the sub-lists contain? `list_a` shows only 2 elements per list, but the code seems to imply there are more?

Comment: There are six elements in each sub-list. I have updated the question.

Comment: I'd probably just do something like `list_b = ['{}, {}\n'.format(datetime.fromtimestamp(int(i[0]) / 1000), ', '.join(i[1:])) for i in list_a]`